# Flutter Firebase phone auth SMS message with OTP not being received

Tags: flutter, firebase, firebase-authentication, totp

I'm facing issues with the phone authentication process in my Flutter app. Despite following the phone auth documentation, configuring SHA-1 and SHA-256 fingerprints, and enabling phone auth in Firebase, I'm not receiving the SMS message containing the OTP.

Here is my code :

-> Login  screen

```
import 'package:flutter/material.dart';
import 'package:flutter_bloc/flutter_bloc.dart';
import 'package:go_router/go_router.dart';
import 'package:google_maps/bussiness_logic/cubit/phone_auth_cubit/phone_auth_cubit.dart';
import 'package:google_maps/constants/strings.dart';
import 'package:google_maps/functions.dart';
import 'package:google_maps/presentation/widgets/intro_text.dart';
import 'package:google_maps/presentation/widgets/custom_button.dart';
import 'package:google_maps/presentation/widgets/phone_form_field.dart';

class LoginScreenBody extends StatelessWidget {
  final GlobalKey<FormState> _phoneFormKey = GlobalKey<FormState>();
  TextEditingController phoneFieldController = TextEditingController();

  LoginScreenBody({
    super.key,
  });

  PhoneAuthCubit phoneAuthCubit = PhoneAuthCubit();

  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return BlocProvider<PhoneAuthCubit>(
      create: (context) => phoneAuthCubit,
      child: BlocListener<PhoneAuthCubit, PhoneAuthState>(
        listenWhen: (previous, current) => previous != current,
        listener: (context, state) {
          if (state is LoadingState) {
            showProgressIndicator(context);
          } else if (state is ErrorState) {
            ScaffoldMessenger.of(context).showSnackBar(SnackBar(
              content: Text(state.errorMsg),
              backgroundColor: Colors.black,
              duration: const Duration(seconds: 15),
            ));
          } else if (state is PhoneNumberSubmitedState) {
            Navigator.pop(context);
            GoRouter.of(context)
                .push(Strings.kOtpView, extra: phoneFieldController.text);
          } else if (state is ExitLoadingState) {
            Navigator.pop(context);
          }
        },
        child: Form(
          key: _phoneFormKey,
          child: Padding(
            padding: const EdgeInsets.all(10.0),
            child: Column(
              crossAxisAlignment: CrossAxisAlignment.start,
              mainAxisAlignment: MainAxisAlignment.center,
              children: [
                const IntroText(),
                const SizedBox(
                  height: 90,
                ),
                PhoneFormField(
                  phoneFieldController: phoneFieldController,
                ),
                const SizedBox(
                  height: 60,
                ),
                CustomButton(
                  buttonTextValue: "Next",
                  onPressedAction: () {
                    phoneAuthCubit.tapNextButton(
                      context,
                      _phoneFormKey,
                      phoneFieldController,
                    );
                  },
                ),
              ],
            ),
          ),
        ),
      ),
    );
  }
}
```

-> OTP screen

```
import 'package:flutter/material.dart';
import 'package:flutter_bloc/flutter_bloc.dart';
import 'package:go_router/go_router.dart';
import 'package:google_maps/bussiness_logic/cubit/phone_auth_cubit/phone_auth_cubit.dart';
import 'package:google_maps/constants/strings.dart';
import 'package:google_maps/functions.dart';
import 'package:google_maps/presentation/widgets/custom_button.dart';
import 'package:google_maps/presentation/widgets/otp_texts.dart';
import 'package:google_maps/presentation/widgets/pin_code_digits.dart';

class OtpScreenBody extends StatelessWidget {
  OtpScreenBody({super.key, required this.phoneNumber});

  PhoneAuthCubit phoneAuthCubit = PhoneAuthCubit();
  final String phoneNumber;

  late String otpCode;

  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return BlocProvider<PhoneAuthCubit>(
      create: (context) => phoneAuthCubit,
      child: BlocListener<PhoneAuthCubit, PhoneAuthState>(
        listenWhen: (previous, current) => previous != current,
        listener: (context, state) {
          if (state is LoadingState) {
            showProgressIndicator(context);
          } else if (state is ErrorState) {
            ScaffoldMessenger.of(context).showSnackBar(SnackBar(
              content: Text(state.errorMsg),
              backgroundColor: Colors.black,
              duration: const Duration(seconds: 5),
            ));
          } else if (state is OtpVerifiedState) {
            GoRouter.of(context).pushReplacementNamed(Strings.kMapScreen);
          }
        },
        child: Padding(
          padding: const EdgeInsets.all(10.0),
          child: Column(
              crossAxisAlignment: CrossAxisAlignment.start,
              mainAxisAlignment: MainAxisAlignment.center,
              children: [
                OtpTexts(
                  phoneNumber: phoneNumber,
                ),
                const SizedBox(
                  height: 88,
                ),
                PinCodeDigits(phoneAuthCubit: phoneAuthCubit),
                const SizedBox(
                  height: 60,
                ),
                CustomButton(
                  buttonTextValue: 'Submit',
                  onPressedAction: () {
                    phoneAuthCubit.tapSubmitButton();
                  },
                )
              ]),
        ),
      ),
    );
  }
}
```

```
import 'package:flutter/material.dart';
import 'package:google_maps/constants/my_colors.dart';

class OtpTexts extends StatelessWidget {
  const OtpTexts({super.key, required this.phoneNumber});

  final String phoneNumber;

  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return Column(
      crossAxisAlignment: CrossAxisAlignment.start,
      children: [
        const Text(
          'Verify your phone numberr',
          style: TextStyle(
            fontSize: 24,
            fontWeight: FontWeight.bold,
            color: Colors.black,
          ),
        ),
        const SizedBox(
          height: 20,
        ),
        Container(
          margin: const EdgeInsets.symmetric(horizontal: 2),
          child: RichText(
            text: TextSpan(
                text: 'Enter your 6 digits code numbers sent to you at ',
                style: const TextStyle(
                  fontSize: 18,
                  fontWeight: FontWeight.w500,
                  color: Colors.black,
                ),
                children: <TextSpan>[
                  TextSpan(
                      text: '+2$phoneNumber',
                      style:
                          const TextStyle(color: MyColors.blue, fontSize: 16))
                ]),
          ),
        ),
      ],
    );
  }
}
```

```
import 'package:firebase_auth/firebase_auth.dart';
import 'package:flutter/material.dart';
import 'package:flutter_bloc/flutter_bloc.dart';

part 'phone_auth_state.dart';

class PhoneAuthCubit extends Cubit<PhoneAuthState> {
  String verificationId = '';
  late String otpCode;
  final TextEditingController fieldOne = TextEditingController();
  final TextEditingController fieldTwo = TextEditingController();
  final TextEditingController fieldThree = TextEditingController();
  final TextEditingController fieldFour = TextEditingController();
  final TextEditingController fieldFive = TextEditingController();
  final TextEditingController fieldSex = TextEditingController();

  PhoneAuthCubit() : super(PhoneAuthInitial());

  Future<void> submitPhoneNumber(String phoneNumber) async {
    print(phoneNumber);
    emit(LoadingState());

    await FirebaseAuth.instance.verifyPhoneNumber(
      phoneNumber: '+2$phoneNumber',
      timeout: const Duration(seconds: 14),
      verificationCompleted: verificationCompleted,
      verificationFailed: verificationFailed,
      codeSent: codeSent,
      codeAutoRetrievalTimeout: codeAutoRetrievalTimeout,
    );
  }

  void verificationCompleted(PhoneAuthCredential credential) async {
    print('verificationCompleted');
    await signIn(credential);
  }

  void verificationFailed(FirebaseAuthException error) {
    print('verificationFailed : ${error.toString()}');
    emit(ErrorState(errorMsg: error.toString()));
  }

  void codeSent(String verificationId, int? resendToken) {
    print('codeSent');
    this.verificationId = verificationId;
    emit(PhoneNumberSubmitedState());
  }

  void codeAutoRetrievalTimeout(String verificationId) {
    print('codeAutoRetrievalTimeout');
  }

  Future<void> submitOTP(String otpCode) async {
    PhoneAuthCredential credential = PhoneAuthProvider.credential(
        verificationId: this.verificationId, smsCode: otpCode);

    await signIn(credential);
  }

  Future<void> signIn(PhoneAuthCredential credential) async {
    try {
      await FirebaseAuth.instance.signInWithCredential(credential);
      emit(OtpVerifiedState());
    } catch (error) {
      emit(ErrorState(errorMsg: error.toString()));
    }
  }

  Future<void> logOut() async {
    await FirebaseAuth.instance.signOut();
  }

  User getLoggedInUser() {
    User firebaseUser = FirebaseAuth.instance.currentUser!;
    return firebaseUser;
  }

  Future<void> tapNextButton(
      BuildContext context,
      GlobalKey<FormState> phoneFormKey,
      TextEditingController phoneController) async {
    emit(LoadingState());
    await Future.delayed(const Duration(seconds: 1));

    if (phoneFormKey.currentState!.validate()) {
      phoneFormKey.currentState!.save();
      submitPhoneNumber(phoneController.text);
      emit(
          PhoneNumberSubmitedState()); // fire bloc listener to handle that state
    } else {
      // entered unvalid phone number
      emit(ExitLoadingState());
    }
  }

  Future<void> tapSubmitButton() async {
    emit(LoadingState());

    if (fieldOne.text.isEmpty ||
        fieldTwo.text.isEmpty ||
        fieldThree.text.isEmpty ||
        fieldFour.text.isEmpty ||
        fieldFive.text.isEmpty ||
        fieldSex.text.isEmpty) {
      emit(ErrorState(errorMsg: "Please fill in all fields"));
      return;
    }

    otpCode = fieldOne.text +
        fieldTwo.text +
        fieldThree.text +
        fieldFour.text +
        fieldFive.text +
        fieldSex.text;

    submitOTP(otpCode);
  }
}`
```

loginBody --> where i enter the phone number .

**log output:**

```
Connecting to VM Service at ws://127.0.0.1:63570/wbNXq9n5oQ0=/ws
W/MIUIScout ANR( 5906): AnrScout only want msg within 20s, so stop here
D/MIUIScout ANR( 5906): get period history msg: (Current message:null)
D/MIUIScout ANR( 5906): get period history msg:execute time\>50ms (msgIndex=4seq=4 plan=١٣:٥٦:٥٤.١٦٥ late=53ms wall=118ms running=0ms h=android.app.ActivityThread$H w=159)
D/MIUIScout ANR( 5906): get period history msg:In recent 20s, total historyMsgCount=343
I/ple.google_map( 5906): Thread\[6,tid=5915,WaitingInMainSignalCatcherLoop,Thread\*=0xb400007cba832000,peer=0x12cc1768,"Signal Catcher"\]: reacting to signal 3
I/ple.google_map( 5906):
I/ple.google_map( 5906): Wrote stack traces to tombstoned
2
W/InputMethodManager( 5906): Ignoring showSoftInput() as view=io.flutter.embedding.android.FlutterView{26421c9 VFE...... .F....ID 0,0-1080,2270 #1} is not served.
D/DecorView\[\]( 5906): onWindowFocusChanged hasWindowFocus true
D/MIUIInput( 5906): \[KeyEvent\] ViewRootImpl KeyEvent { action=ACTION_UP, keyCode=KEYCODE_VOLUME_DOWN, scanCode=114, metaState=0, flags=0x8, repeatCount=0, eventTime=26582407, downTime=26582275, deviceId=2, source=0x101, displayId=-1 }
W/MIUIInput( 5906): AnrScout input event latency is 7119
W/MirrorManager( 5906): this model don't Support
D/InputMethodManager( 5906): showSoftInput() view=io.flutter.embedding.android.FlutterView{26421c9 VFE...... .F...... 0,0-1080,2270 #1 aid=1073741824} flags=0 reason=SHOW_SOFT_INPUT
D/InsetsController( 5906): show(ime(), fromIme=true)
D/InputMethodManager( 5906): showSoftInput() view=io.flutter.embedding.android.FlutterView{26421c9 VFE...... .F...... 0,0-1080,2270 #1 aid=1073741824} flags=0 reason=SHOW_SOFT_INPUT
D/InsetsController( 5906): show(ime(), fromIme=true)
D/InputMethodManager( 5906): showSoftInput() view=io.flutter.embedding.android.FlutterView{26421c9 VFE...... .F...... 0,0-1080,2270 #1 aid=1073741824} flags=0 reason=SHOW_SOFT_INPUT
D/InsetsController( 5906): show(ime(), fromIme=true)
D/InputMethodManager( 5906): showSoftInput() view=io.flutter.embedding.android.FlutterView{26421c9 VFE...... .F...... 0,0-1080,2270 #1 aid=1073741824} flags=0 reason=SHOW_SOFT_INPUT
D/InsetsController( 5906): show(ime(), fromIme=true)
D/InputMethodManager( 5906): showSoftInput() view=io.flutter.embedding.android.FlutterView{26421c9 VFE...... .F...... 0,0-1080,2270 #1 aid=1073741824} flags=0 reason=SHOW_SOFT_INPUT
D/InsetsController( 5906): show(ime(), fromIme=true)
D/InputMethodManager( 5906): showSoftInput() view=io.flutter.embedding.android.FlutterView{26421c9 VFE...... .F...... 0,0-1080,2270 #1 aid=1073741824} flags=0 reason=SHOW_SOFT_INPUT
D/InsetsController( 5906): show(ime(), fromIme=true)
D/DecorView\[\]( 5906): onWindowFocusChanged hasWindowFocus false
D/DecorView\[\]( 5906): onWindowFocusChanged hasWindowFocus true
D/InputMethodManager( 5906): showSoftInput() view=io.flutter.embedding.android.FlutterView{26421c9 VFE...... .F...... 0,0-1080,2270 #1 aid=1073741824} flags=0 reason=SHOW_SOFT_INPUT
D/InsetsController( 5906): show(ime(), fromIme=true)
D/InputMethodManager( 5906): showSoftInput() view=io.flutter.embedding.android.FlutterView{26421c9 VFE...... .F...... 0,0-1080,2270 #1 aid=1073741824} flags=0 reason=SHOW_SOFT_INPUT
D/InsetsController( 5906): show(ime(), fromIme=true)
D/InputMethodManager( 5906): showSoftInput() view=io.flutter.embedding.android.FlutterView{26421c9 VFE...... .F...... 0,0-1080,2270 #1 aid=1073741824} flags=0 reason=SHOW_SOFT_INPUT
D/InsetsController( 5906): show(ime(), fromIme=true)
D/InputMethodManager( 5906): showSoftInput() view=io.flutter.embedding.android.FlutterView{26421c9 VFE...... .F...... 0,0-1080,2270 #1 aid=1073741824} flags=0 reason=SHOW_SOFT_INPUT
D/InsetsController( 5906): show(ime(), fromIme=true)
D/InputMethodManager( 5906): showSoftInput() view=io.flutter.embedding.android.FlutterView{26421c9 VFE...... .F...... 0,0-1080,2270 #1 aid=1073741824} flags=0 reason=SHOW_SOFT_INPUT
D/InsetsController( 5906): show(ime(), fromIme=true)
D/InputMethodManager( 5906): showSoftInput() view=io.flutter.embedding.android.FlutterView{26421c9 VFE...... .F...... 0,0-1080,2270 #1 aid=1073741824} flags=0 reason=SHOW_SOFT_INPUT
D/InsetsController( 5906): show(ime(), fromIme=true)
I/flutter ( 5906): 01005355825
I/zzb     ( 5906): ForceRecaptchaFlow from phoneAuthOptions = false, ForceRecaptchaFlow from firebaseSettings = false
W/System  ( 5906): Ignoring header X-Firebase-Locale because its value was null.
2
D/InputMethodManager( 5906): showSoftInput() view=io.flutter.embedding.android.FlutterView{26421c9 VFE...... .F...... 0,0-1080,2270 #1 aid=1073741824} flags=0 reason=SHOW_SOFT_INPUT
D/InsetsController( 5906): show(ime(), fromIme=true)
I/AssistStructure( 5906): Flattened final assist data: 392 bytes, containing 1 windows, 3 views
D/InsetsController( 5906): show(ime(), fromIme=true)
I/PlayCore( 5906): UID: \[10261\]  PID: \[5906\] IntegrityService : requestIntegrityToken(IntegrityTokenRequest{nonce=7bXOSNhNlUgCWuHzy9mDBhQA9o0vfL5Z918aSxdmUDs, cloudProjectNumber=551503664846})
I/PlayCore( 5906): UID: \[10261\]  PID: \[5906\] IntegrityService : Initiate binding to the service.
I/PlayCore( 5906): UID: \[10261\]  PID: \[5906\] IntegrityService : ServiceConnectionImpl.onServiceConnected(ComponentInfo{com.android.vending/com.google.android.finsky.integrityservice.IntegrityService})
I/PlayCore( 5906): UID: \[10261\]  PID: \[5906\] IntegrityService : linkToDeath
I/PlayCore( 5906): UID: \[10261\]  PID: \[5906\] OnRequestIntegrityTokenCallback : onRequestIntegrityToken
I/PlayCore( 5906): UID: \[10261\]  PID: \[5906\] IntegrityService : Unbind from service.
W/System  ( 5906): Ignoring header X-Firebase-Locale because its value was null.
E/FirebaseAuth( 5906): \[SmsRetrieverHelper\] SMS verification code request failed: unknown status code: 18002 Invalid PlayIntegrity token; app not Recognized by Play Store.
D/FirebaseAuth( 5906): Re-triggering phone verification with Recaptcha flow forced for phone number +201005355825
I/zzb     ( 5906): ForceRecaptchaFlow from phoneAuthOptions = true, ForceRecaptchaFlow from firebaseSettings = false
D/IS_CTS_MODE( 5906): false
D/MULTI_WINDOW_SWITCH_ENABLED( 5906): false
D/DecorView\[\]( 5906): getWindowModeFromSystem  windowmode is 1
W/Activity( 5906): PerfMonitor: Slow Operation: Activity com.example.google_maps/com.google.firebase.auth.internal.RecaptchaActivity onResume took 666ms
W/System  ( 5906): Ignoring header X-Firebase-Locale because its value was null.
W/Looper  ( 5906): PerfMonitor looperActivity : package=com.example.google_maps/com.google.firebase.auth.internal.RecaptchaActivity time=0ms latency=687ms running=0ms  procState=-1  historyMsgCount=2 (msgIndex=2 wall=685ms seq=767 late=2ms h=android.app.ActivityThread$H w=159)
D/DecorView\[\]( 5906): onWindowFocusChanged hasWindowFocus false
D/DecorView\[\]( 5906): onWindowFocusChanged hasWindowFocus true
E/FirebaseAuth( 5906): \[GetAuthDomainTask\] Error getting project config. Failed with INVALID_CERT_HASH 400
E/zzb     ( 5906): Failed to get reCAPTCHA token with error \[There was an error while trying to get your package certificate hash.\]- calling backend without app verification
W/System  ( 5906): Ignoring header X-Firebase-Locale because its value was null.
D/DecorView\[\]( 5906): onWindowFocusChanged hasWindowFocus false
D/DecorView\[\]( 5906): onWindowFocusChanged hasWindowFocus true
E/FirebaseAuth( 5906): \[SmsRetrieverHelper\] SMS verification code request failed: unknown status code: 17093 null
I/flutter ( 5906): verificationFailed : \[firebase_auth/missing-client-identifier\] This request is missing a valid app identifier, meaning that Play Integrity checks, and reCAPTCHA checks were unsuccessful. Please try again, or check the logcat for more details.
D/DecorView\[\]( 5906): onWindowFocusChanged hasWindowFocus false
E/BLASTBufferQueue( 5906): \[ViewRootImpl\[MainActivity\]#0\](f:0,a:2) Applying pending transactions on dtor 1
W/ple.google_map( 5906): Cleared Reference was only reachable from finalizer (only reported once)
W/JavaBinder( 5906): BinderProxy is being destroyed but the application did not call unlinkToDeath to unlink all of its death recipients beforehand.  Releasing leaked death recipient: com.google.android.play.integrity.internal.n
I/BpBinder( 5906): onLastStrongRef automatically unlinking death recipients: \<uncached descriptor\>
W/System  ( 5906): A resource failed to call end
```

Comment: Please trim your code to make it easier to find your problem. Follow these guidelines to create a [minimal reproducible example](https://stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example).